# Pandas pivoting and adding a column from CSV with consecutive rows

Tags: python, database, pandas

I have consecutive row duplicates in two column. 
I want to delete the second row duplicate based on [col1,col2] and move the value of another column to a new one.

Example:

Input

```
col1 col2 col3
  X    A   1
  X    A   2
  Y    A   3
  Y    A   4
  X    B   5
  X    B   6
  Z    C   7
  Z    C   8
```

Output

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
 X    A    1    2
 Y    A    3    4
 X    B    5    6
 Z    C    7    8
```

I found out about pivoting but I am struggling to understand how to add another column and avoid indexing, I would to preserve everything as written in the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to Question 10 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe):

```
(df.assign(col=df.groupby(['col1','col2']).cumcount())
   .pivot_table(index=['col1','col2'], columns='col', values='col3')
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
col col1 col2  0  1
0      X    A  1  2
1      X    B  5  6
2      Y    A  3  4
3      Z    C  7  8
```